# Text is appearing in the background of the table how to make text appear after table?

Tags: tables, pdftex

I created a table in latex. All text after the table is appearing in the background of the table. Also centering property is not working. I want this table to be center or in the middle of the page.

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Type}                            & \textbf{Database Name} & 
\textbf{Anger} & \textbf{Disgust}        & \textbf{Fear} & 
\textbf{Happiness} & \textbf{Sadness} & \textbf{Surprise} & \textbf{Total 
Images} \\ \hline
                                     & CK+                    &                
& {\color[HTML]{333333} } &               &                    &                  
&                   &                       \\ \cline{2-9}
                                     & JAFFE                  &                 
&                         &               &                    &                  
&                   &                       \\ \cline{2-9}
                                     & RaFD                   &                
&                         &               &                    &                  
&                   &                       \\ \cline{2-9}
\multirow{-4}{*}{\textbf{Train Dataset}} & TFEID                  &                
&                         &               &                    &                  
&                   &                       \\ \hline
                                     & CK+                    &                
&                         &               &                    &                  
&                   &                       \\ \cline{2-9}
                                     & JAFFE                  &                
&                         &               &                    &                  
&                   &                       \\ \cline{2-9}
                                     & RaFD                   &                
&                         &               &                    &                  
&                   &                       \\ \cline{2-9}
\multirow{-4}{*}{\textbf{Test Dataset}}  & TFEID                  &                
&                         &               &                    &                  
&                   &                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Here is screenshot]

Comment: There's something that you have shown us that is causing the problem (which is at least obvious because you haven't given the text for the references [7] and [8]).  I don't suppose you're in two column mode?  It almost looks like your table is trying to be in the left column but bleeds over to the right.

Comment: @Teepeemm I am in two column mode. I updated the screenshot.

Comment: you have made the table too wide to fit in a column. either reformat it to be narrower to use `\begin{table*}` so it spans both columns

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did it. No change. If I reformated the table now it can be set in the middle of one column. But my table is big so I have to show it in two columns.

Comment: in any normal class the layout of table* and table are completely different so if you got no change you are using some _very_ non standard code, Please _always_ provide a test file that shows the problem no one can debug your fragment.

Comment: If I use table* the whole table just disappears.

Comment: Please tell us which document class, and which font size, you employ.

Comment: @Mico  I am using this class "\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}" and these packages \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[backend = bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq it will not disappear it may go to another page, but you need to provide an example. If you do not want `table*` then reformat your table to fit within column width. It is your data, you are best placed to reformat it if you want it to fit in a column.

Comment: Another possibility would be to nest  your `tabular` in a `strip` environment (`cuted` package). As it won't be floating any more, you'll have to use `\captionof{table}{Some caption}`.